# ASN.1 Java Compiler

Tags: java, asn.1

Is there any ASN.1 Java Compiler that is not licensed under the GPL?

I have tried bouncycastle but it doesn't compile to Java. I want to look at Apache Harmony ASN.1 framework but it has been terminated.

Comment: Why must is be not-GPL; are you worried that when you use it this would force you to make your own code GPL? That would only be true if you create some product that extends the GPL program; not if you only use it to for example generate code.

Comment: Reason being is that, after I have the compiled java classes. I will still use the (i.e. Java ASN.1 Compiler) library in my code. Should I opensource my code as well?

Comment: If you include it as a JAR with your software and it's GPL, then you might indeed be forced to GPL your own software as well. For situations like these the [LGPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License) was invented; if the ASN.1 compiler is LGPL-licensed, you would be able to include it as a JAR without making your own software GPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using a commercial ASN.1 Tool.  These are not GPL-based.  A good list of tools (both free and commercial) can be found at http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/links/index.htm.  Please consider downloading a free trial of one of the commercial tools to see if that will work for you.

Comment: Hi. Yeah we tried ASN.1 compiler from OSS but it was really expensive. Looking at Google Proto-buff too but it wasn't compatible with ASN.1. Anyway thanks for the link.

Comment: OSS offers a variety of licensing and pricing models (http://www.oss.com/products/purchase.html) to match many
different needs.   OSS ASN.1 commercial products are a cost effective solution for even the most cost budget constrained projects.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what your specific experience was and I am not at liberty to disclose purchase details, but I found that OSS offers a variety of flexible licensing and pricing models.   I recommend that you visit http://www.oss.com/products/purchase.html.  I have found the OSS Nokalva ASN.1 tools software to be very reasonably priced and to deliver an extremely cost effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

Because JAC (Java ASN.1 Compiler) is licensed under the GPL and has BER coding errors I decided to implement a new Java ASN.1 compiler + library called jASN1 licensed under the LGPL available from https://www.openmuc.org/index.php?id=60. It may satisfy your needs.

Comment: Recommendation requests for off-site resources or tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you answer them, you specifically reinforce the belief that Stack Overflow is a good place to answer those questions. It is not. Please don't answer these questions even if you know a good answer as most answers will be highly opinionated ("I personally like..."). You can open the flag dialogue on the question and see the close reason in full under the **off-topic** category, or in the [help/on-topic]. You should also not even answer in a comment, as the effect is similar to an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try our compiler, [Objective System's ASN1C](https://www.obj-sys.com/products/asn1c/index.php).  I'm not sure why it doesn't appear in the ASN.1:2008 section on the ITU page that Paul gave you; I believe it should.  Don't let that strike it from your consideration.

Comment: is it for free? if so why the registration is required?

Comment: @M_E No, it is a commercial tool.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @FrontMobe I fixed the link.